# Finding the instance of a model not true:class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I currently have a method that returns true or false if a record exists?. It does it's job find but I need to return that record that it found and update it with new information. The code I have right now does not as I want it to. Here is my code

## Model method:

```
def self.stored?(image_path)
  md5 = Digest::MD5.file(image_path).hexdigest

  FailedImage.where(md5: md5).exists?
end
```

This returns a true class. I want it to return a record.

## controller

```
if failed_image = FailedImage.stored?(context.download_path)
  failed_image.update_from_image_optimization(context.image_optimization)
end
```

I get this error `undefined method update_from_image_optimization for true:TrueClass` This is because it is returning true class when I want a record. Anybody know how I can achieve this?

Comment: Ruby convention is for methods ending in question mark to return booleans. So if the purpose of the method changes, it might be smart to change the name too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `exists?` from `FailedImage.where(md5: md5)`.

This would return you an array of records.

Model method should look as follows:

```
def self.stored?(image_path)
  md5 = Digest::MD5.file(image_path).hexdigest
  FailedImage.where(md5: md5)
end
```